# Phoenix UndefinedFunctionError

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I do (in `iex -S mix`):

```
alias Sling.Accounts.User
User.changeset(%User{},%{})
```

Works fine, but when I add the line:
User.registration_changeset(%User{}, %{})

I get:

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Sling.Accounts.User.registration_changeset/2 is undefined or private
>           (sling) Sling.Accounts.User.registration_changeset(%Sling.Accounts.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "users">, email: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, password_hash: nil, updated_at: nil, username: nil}, %{})

**What am I doing wrong?**

User model below:

```
defmodule Sling.User do
  use Sling.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :username, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:username, :email])
    |> validate_required([:username, :email])
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end

  def registration_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> changeset(params)
    |> cast(params, [:password]
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
    |> put_password_hash()
  end

  defp put_password_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, ComeoninBcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: According to your code, `registration_changeset` is in `Sling.User`, not `Sling.Accounts.User`.

Comment: Yep, that explains everything. I've mixed 1.2 and 1.3 code together, and have user models in two places ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help!